Comunicación entre fragment imposible , Fragment xxx not associated whit a fragment manager (java)
Llevo varios días atascado en este paso. Estoy haciendo app para aficionados a las Plantas en la que muestro una serie de fichas, además es posible realizar la clasificación de una planta determinada siguiendo las claves de Flora Ibérica.
La aplicación consta de varios adaptadores para mostrar las fichas, los listados, los criterios etc. cada una de las funciones se realiza en un fragment 'alojado' en un Activity_Main y en un ViewPager2 asociado a un TabLayout.
Algunas comunicaciones entre fragments fallan y otras no, es algo incomprensible, me explico:
En el Fragment2 (zz_2_clave_clasificar) se realiza la clasificación respondiendo a diversas cuestiones hasta llegar al nivel de familia, obtenido este resultado lo paso a Fragment 1 para que muestre las fichas de imágenes correspondientes a esa familia mediante un bundle y a Fragment 3 para que muestre los géneros de esa familia:
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("num", "Hay " + fich + " fichas.");
            bundle.putString("consulta", consultaCrear);
            getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResult("key", bundle);

            Bundle bundleGen = new Bundle();
            bundleGen.putInt("lista", idFamiliaHallada);
            getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResult("key3", bundleGen);

El primero con la clave "key" sirve para el fragmento 1 (fichas) y
el segundo con la clave "key3" sirve para el fragmento 3 (géneros)
"key2" se recibe desde fragmento 5 cuando se ha buscado una planta y se ha encontrado.
Cuando deslizo hacia a la izquierda (fragmento 2 --> fragmento 1) las imágenes se actualizan a las correspondientes a esa familia--> Fragmento 1 (zz_1_fichas):
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener("key", this, new FragmentResultListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFragmentResult(@NonNull String requestKey, @NonNull Bundle result) {
            str = result.getString("num");
            String consultaCrear = result.getString("consulta");
            allPlantasTotal = new ArrayList<>();
            allPlantasTotal = realizarBusqueda(consultaCrear);
            if (mAdapter.getItemCount() > 0) {
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            cargarRecycler(allPlantasTotal);
            tV2.setText(str);
        }
    });

    getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener("key2", this, new FragmentResultListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFragmentResult(@NonNull String requestKey, @NonNull Bundle result) {
            int posicion = result.getInt("posicion");
            mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(posicion);
        }
    });
}

Si deslizo a la derecha (fragmento 2 --> fragmento 3) las lista de géneros de esa familia sale actualizada,esa lista esta manejada por un adaptador en el que habilito el "onItemClick".
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    hallados = new ArrayList<>();
    //========= Recoge datos desde clave_clasificar <---- (int) idFamilia clasificada
        getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener("key3", this, new FragmentResultListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFragmentResult(@NonNull String requestKey, @NonNull Bundle result) {
                int faml = result.getInt("lista");
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Recibido de FragmentManager correcto, con key3 y list(idFamilia)= " + faml, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                obtenerGeneros(faml);
            }
        });
    }

Estos dos 'envíos' funcionan bien y hasta ahora no han dado problemas.
Ahora viene el problema, cuando hago click en un ítem de la lista de géneros debería conectar con Google en el fragmento 4 para mostrar la actualización de ese genero de plantas -->
    El fragment 3 completo:---------------->

    package com.ajfm.plantas.fragmentos;

    import static com.ajfm.plantas.MainActivity.myViewPager2;
    import static com.ajfm.plantas.MainActivity.tabLayout;
    import static com.ajfm.plantas.SplashActivity.allGeneros;

    import android.os.Bundle;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentResultListener;
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.ajfm.plantas.R;
    import com.ajfm.plantas.adaptadores.AdaptadorGenero;
    import com.ajfm.plantas.modelos.genero;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class zz_3_generoFragm extends Fragment implements AdaptadorGenero.OnItemClickListener {

    private TextView tVgen;
    private View view;
    private RecyclerView gRecyclerViewG;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager glayoutManagerG;
    private AdaptadorGenero gAdapterG;
    public static List<genero> hallados;
    public static String generoElecto;
    private FrameLayout fLy;
   
    public zz_3_generoFragm() {
    // Required empty public constructor
    }    


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    hallados = new ArrayList<>();
    //========= Recoge datos desde clave_clasificar <---- (int) idFamilia clasificada
        getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener("key3", this, new FragmentResultListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFragmentResult(@NonNull String requestKey, @NonNull Bundle     result) {
                int faml = result.getInt("lista");
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Recibido de FragmentManager correcto, con key3 y list(idFamilia)= " + faml, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                obtenerGeneros(faml);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_zz_3_genero, container, false);
    tVgen = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tVgen);
    return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    
    fLy = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.fragLy);
    gRecyclerViewG = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rCy);
    gRecyclerViewG.setHasFixedSize(true); //si sabemos que no va a zz_7_cambiar de tamaño
    gRecyclerViewG.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    glayoutManagerG = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    gRecyclerViewG.setLayoutManager(glayoutManagerG);
    gAdapterG = new AdaptadorGenero(allGeneros, R.layout.ungenero);
    gRecyclerViewG.setAdapter(gAdapterG);
    gAdapterG.setOnItemClickListener(new zz_3_generoFragm());

    int hay = allGeneros.size();
    String heys = Integer.toString(hay);
    String str = "Hay " + heys + " géneros en total";
    tVgen.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_GRAVITY);
    tVgen.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    tVgen.setText(str);
    }

    @Override
    public void OnItemClick(View v, int position) {
    if (position >= 0) {
        String genYesp = hallados.get(position).getgGeneroyFamilia();
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Pulsado sobre " + genYesp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("genYesp",genYesp);
        getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResult("key4",b);
        tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(3));
        myViewPager2.setCurrentItem(3);

        zz_4_webFrag newFragment = new zz_4_webFrag();
        newFragment.setArguments(b);

        FragmentManager fm = getParentFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragLy, newFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } else {
        String no = "No hay ninguna familia seleccionada ";
        tVgen.setText(no);
    }
   
    }
    private void obtenerGeneros(int fimili) {
    for (genero egen : allGeneros) {
        if (egen.getgIdFamilia() == (fimili)) {
            hallados.add(egen);
        }
    }
    int hay = hallados.size();
    if (hay > 0) {
        gAdapterG = new AdaptadorGenero(hallados, R.layout.ungenero);
        gRecyclerViewG.setAdapter(gAdapterG);
        gAdapterG.notifyDataSetChanged();
        String heys = Integer.toString(hay);
        String str = heys + " géneros en " + hallados.get(0).getgFamilia();
        tVgen.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_GRAVITY);
        tVgen.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        tVgen.setText(str);
    } else {
        Log.d("nohay", "No hay generos en la familia con ese id:" + fimili);
    }
    }

}
Entonces aparece el 'cuelgue', lo que quiero es que se abra directamente el fragmento 4 con la búsqueda en Google del género envíado ya hecha.
Si hago debug línea a línea falla en: getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResult("key4",b);
He probado con varios adaptadores para el ViewPager2, con getChilFragmentManager, y otras variantes,  he buscado en infinidad de sitios pero en todos lados encuentro que la forma de hacerlo es con getParentFragmentManager ...etc.
El error que me devuelve es Fragmento no asociado con ningún fragment manager, no entiendo que 'encontrando' un getParentFragmentManager en onCreate y recuperando el dato envíado desde Fragment 2, ahora diga que no tiene ningún FragmentManager asociado¡¡¡¡
He hecho una app paralela con 8 fragments y he hecho traspasos de datos entre ellos y parece funcionar bien, algo lenta la actualización de los 'slide'. Los datos estan en una base de datos SQLite y funcionan bien.

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ajfm.plantas, PID: 32430
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment zz_3_generoFragm{43911c4}
(91d53a2e-537c-493d-9e28-a8bad98da52f) not associated with a fragmentmanager.
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getParentFragmentManager(Fragment.java:1113)
at com.ajfm.plantas.fragmentos.zz_3_generoFragm.OnItemClick(zz_3_generoFragm.java:156)
at com.ajfm.plantas.adaptadores.AdaptadorGenero$ViewHolder$1.onClick(AdaptadorGenero.java:53)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

Adjunto el gradle:______________________________________________
    plugins {id("com.android.application")}
    android {
    namespace = "com.ajfm.plantas"
    compileSdk = 34
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "com.ajfm.plantas"
    minSdk = 24
    targetSdk = 34
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
    release {
        isMinifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-                     rules.pro")
    }
    }
    compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("https://www.jitpack.io")
        }
    }
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url = uri("https://www.jitpack.io") }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    implementation("com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828")
    implementation("com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment:1.8.0-alpha02")
    implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.7.0")
    implementation("com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0")
    implementation("androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0")
      }
  }
  dependencies {
      implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
      implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0")
      implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
      implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.7")
      implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.7")
  }

El adaptador de ViewPager2 :------------------------------------------------------------
    package com.ajfm.plantas.adaptadores;
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
    import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
    import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter;

    import com.ajfm.plantas.fragmentos.zz_1_fichas;
    import com.ajfm.plantas.fragmentos.zz_2_clave_clasificar;
    import com.ajfm.plantas.fragmentos.zz_3_generoFragm;
    import com.ajfm.plantas.fragmentos.zz_4_webFrag;
    import com.ajfm.plantas.fragmentos.zz_5_buscar;
    import com.ajfm.plantas.fragmentos.zz_6_agregar;
    import com.ajfm.plantas.fragmentos.zz_7_cambiar;
    import com.ajfm.plantas.fragmentos.zz_8_salir;

    public class ViewPagerAdapter2 extends FragmentStateAdapter {

        public ViewPagerAdapter2(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull         Lifecycle lifecycle) {
    super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
            switch (position){
        case 0: return new zz_1_fichas();
        case 1: return new zz_2_clave_clasificar();
        case 2: return new zz_3_generoFragm();
        case 3: return new zz_4_webFrag();
        case 4: return new zz_5_buscar();
        case 5: return new zz_6_agregar();
        case 6: return new zz_7_cambiar();
        default: return new zz_8_salir();
      }
    }
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 8;
}

}
En MainActivity onCreate -->
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.view_pager2);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);


    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    widthTotal = metrics.widthPixels; // ancho absoluto en pixels
    heightTotal = metrics.heightPixels; // alto absoluto en pixels
    widthImg = widthTotal - 15;
    heightImg = heightTotal - 15;

    myViewPager2.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
    myAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter2(getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());
    myViewPager2.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    myViewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(position));
        }
   
    TabLayoutMediator tabLayoutMediator = new TabLayoutMediator(
            tabLayout, myViewPager2, true, new      TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
        @Override
        public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
            tab.setText(labels[position]);
        }
    });
    tabLayoutMediator.attach();

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            myViewPager2.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
}

Y los layout :-----------------activity_main.xml-------------->
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://        schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/naranjin"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/view_pager2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/cel_claro"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tab_layout">


        </androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Solo pongo el layout de fragment 3 que es el que da problemas:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/fragLy"
        tools:context=".fragmentos.zz_3_generoFragm">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVgen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/grisin"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/genero"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#263238"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

      <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rCy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:background="@color/cel_claro"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tVgen">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

Perdón por la extensión, espero que a pesar de extensa mi pregunta sea comprensible, muchas gracias de antemano.
